# Is "make: *** empty variable name. Stop." after configuring gcc a user error or bug?

Tags: compiling, gcc

After `contrib/download_prerequisites` and

```
env CC=/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc \
LD=/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ld \
RANLIB=/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ranlib \
AR=/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ar \
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/libc/include-mhard-float-mfpu=vfpv3-d16" \
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib" \
./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local --enable-obsolete --enable-languages=c,c++
```

in gcc git source root I'm getting `make: *** empty variable name.  Stop.` and cannot remotely figure out why this is the case. I assume that the `gcc` build system works, but then why does it create an errornous `Makefile`? See the detailed log at https://travis-ci.org/krichter722/gcc/jobs/203079228.

I checked [Makefile error: empty variable name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154047/makefile-error-empty-variable-name), but it only covers the case when the user is creating the Makefile directly which I'm not doing.

Comment: You may want to check the following errors/warnings over at your end: "export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rwky/redis/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rwky/redis/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead." and also this one in particular "/home/travis/build/krichter722/gcc/missing: 81: /home/travis/build/krichter722/gcc/missing: makeinfo: not found"

Comment: What's your `make` version? I'm having the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04 with `make` version `4.1`, while other developers on the team are at Ubuntu 14.04 or RHEL 6.8-ish, with make version `3.81` -- and they're not having any issues... I suspect a regression in `4.1`.

Answer (score 2):

Run your "make" with the following option: --warn-undefined-variables
This will let you know which empty variable make is talking of.

Comment: [It doesn't](https://travis-ci.org/krichter722/gcc/jobs/203083818), unfortunately.

Comment: Then you have to show the Makefile you are running with. There is a rogue " = " in an environment declaration on the command line where from make is getting invoked internally in the Makefile.

Comment: The ``export MAKEFLAGS="-j$((`grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo`*2))"`` command read ``export MAKEFLAGS=="-j$((`grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo`*2))"`` in the `.travis.yml` (but not in the web frontend) - strangest combination of issues I've seen in a while. Since your comment pointed me to it, I'd like to give you credit. I suggest you just edit the question to contain the described issue and if you don't feel comfortable with it add a hint that it's mine. Thank you!